# JQuery toggle() function: switch related img src

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

This is driving me nuts... I have a javascript function which toggles the visibility of an element I pass in using HTML5 techniques. I want to swap the image displayed by the img tag inside the triggering anchor element so that it corresponds to the state of the expanded or collapsed element.

I'm using the following code:

```
    $('a.expand-collapse').click(function () {
    var targetID = $(this).attr('data-expcoltarget');
    var target = $('div#' + targetID);
    debugger;

    target.toggle('blind');

    if (target.is(':visible')) imgSrc = contentRoot + 'images/collapse.gif';
    else imgSrc = contentRoot + 'images/expand.gif'; 

    $(this).find('img').first().attr('src', imgSrc);
});
```

Unfortunately, target.is(':visible') >>always<< returns true, regardless of the visibility state of the target element.

What am I missing?

Edit:

Thanks for being willing to look at the markup, but that turned out not to be necessary to find the solution.

As to what 'data-expcoltarget' is, that's an HTML5 technique for assigning arbitrary values to elements. Anything with the suffix data- gets ignored by the parser.

In this instance I'm using the technique to pass what amounts to an argument into the javascript function. That works because $(this) points to the element that triggered the event, so I can examine its attributes to look for the argument.

Comment: what is `attr('data-expcoltarget')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling `.toggle()` with the `'blind'` parameter, which means it functions as an animation method. The animation happens asynchronously and doesn't complete until after the rest of your click handler has completed.

If you call `.toggle()` with no parameters the toggle will be immediate (no animation) so the rest of your code will work.

If you want to keep the animation, one way to work around the problem is to move your image changing code into the `.toggle()` function's complete callback:

```
$('a.expand-collapse').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        targetID = $this.attr('data-expcoltarget'),
        target = $('#' + targetID);

    target.toggle('blind', function() {
       if (target.is(':visible'))
          imgSrc = contentRoot + 'images/collapse.gif';
       else
          imgSrc = contentRoot + 'images/expand.gif'; 

       $this.find('img').first().attr('src', imgSrc);
    });
});
```

(Note that inside the callback function `this` is the element being toggled, so you need to keep a reference to `$(this)` from outside so that it will refer to the anchor.)

I would probably "simplify" this further to:

```
$('a.expand-collapse').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        targetID = $this.attr('data-expcoltarget'),
        target = $('#' + targetID);

    target.toggle('blind', function() {
       $this.find('img').first().attr('src',
           contentRoot + (target.is(':visible') ? 'images/collapse.gif'
                                                : 'images/expand.gif'));
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, n^6, not only for the solution and the simplification, but also for taking the time to explain why the problem was occurring. I didn't realize toggle() was asynchronous.

Comment: You're welcome. It's easy to overlook the async thing, especially when the no-param version of `.toggle()` is not async. Just in case you didn't know: _all_ jQuery animations are async - they have to be (with each "frame" of the animation done via `setTimeout()` or `setInterval()`) because browsers don't update the page layout while JS is running...